# Can't select value from panel

Tags: jquery, html, css, web

I have a menu and panel (Demo here http://jsfiddle.net/vals/j2LrQ/1/) , the panel depends on the selected menu . 
the problem is when i Turn the mouse into the panel it disappears and i cannt select a value from it .. then i need to know how to make the back color to the menu to full screen as the menu :)

```
body {
    font: 10px normal Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    margin: 10px auto;
    padding: 0;  
}
.container {
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    background:#113388;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

ul#topnav {
   margin: 0; padding: 0;
   float: left;
   list-style: none;
   font-size: 1.2em;
   background: #113388;
   position:relative;
   left:30%;
   text-align:center;
}
ul#topnav li {
   float: left;
   margin: 0; padding: 0;
   border-right: 1px solid #555;
   right:30%;
}
ul#topnav li a {
   padding: 10px 15px;
   display: block;
   color: #f0f0f0;
   text-decoration: none;
   text-align:center;
}

ul#topnav li span {
    padding: 15px 0;
    position: absolute;
                left: 0; top:60px;
                display: none;
                text-align:Center;
                width: 100%;
                background: #558ED5;
                color: #fff;
                -moz-border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
                -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
            }
ul#topnav li:hover span { display: block; }
ul#topnav li span a { display: inline; }
ul#topnav li span a:hover {text-decoration: underline;}
```

Comment: Can you re-phrase your question?  At the moment it's a bit unclear what you're asking.  Also, is all the code you posted relevant to your question, or could it be narrowed down a bit?

Answer (score 1):

A drop down menu works by hovering over a button which in turn causes an action to happen. If there is white space in between the action is cancelled in moving away from it. This means that what you are trying to do cannot in practice be done. The solution below is the best that can be done unless you want to "fake" it. If you don't solution 1 it is. If not move on to solution 2.

**Solution 1**

You need to remove the gap between the main nav bar and the second level nav bar also removing a few things such as your float lefts and left anf right 30% and adding display inline-block fixes the width problem:

http://jsfiddle.net/j2LrQ/5/

```
    body {
    font: 10px normal Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    margin: 10px auto;
    padding: 0;  
}
.container {
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    background:#113388;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

ul#topnav {
   margin: 0; padding: 0;

   list-style: none;
   font-size: 1.2em;
   background: #113388;
   position:relative;
   text-align:center;
}
ul#topnav li {
   display: inline-block;
   margin: 0; padding: 0;
   border-right: 1px solid #555;

}
ul#topnav li a {
   padding: 10px 15px;
   display: block;
   color: #f0f0f0;
   text-decoration: none;
   text-align:center;

}

ul#topnav li span {
    padding: 15px 0;
    position: absolute;
                left: 0; top: 100%;
                display: none;
                text-align:Center;
                width: 100%;
                background: #558ED5;
                color: #fff;
                -moz-border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
                -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
            }
ul#topnav li:hover span { display: block;}
ul#topnav li span a { display: inline;  }
ul#topnav li span a:hover {text-decoration: underline; }
```

**Solution 2**

If you created your buttons as images (this could be in photoshop or gimp or any image editing software) The button would be exactly as you have already created HOWEVER underneath the button you would double up the space with white space. This would give the ILLUSION that there is white space in between the first nav bar and the second level.

Comment: So this solution is almost shows the correct behavior but you want some white space between the top menu and the secondary menu?

Comment: This would be a great deal of effort. You would have to create the buttons as images. The actual button which is blue with the text AND a white part below which "Appears" to not be a button. You would then put them in with the code I have written above. This is because whenever moving your mouse off the button area the hover effect turns off. Otherwise it would stay on constantly even moving your mouse somewhere completely different. Removing the whole point of having a drop down menu.

Comment: The code will be the same as solution 1 however you need to create the buttons as images. If you don't have Photoshop download gimp as its free. Create the buttons if you want them to be 60px with 60px white space create each button 120px in height with half the button half white space.

Comment: I am a bit curious, if you are not proficient in web design, how did you ever get the above to work in the first place?

Comment: In that case I would advice using solution 1 and scrapping the white space between the 2 navbars

Comment: Why do you need the white space?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the effect that you want with a slight change in our HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <ul id="topnav">
        <li ><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Services</a>
                <div class="wrapper">
                    <div class="sec-nav">
                    <a href="#">What We Do</a>
                    <a href="#">Our Process</a>
                    <a href="#">Testimonials</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a>
            <div class="wrapper">
                <div class="sec-nav">
                <a href="#">Web Design</a>
                <a href="#">Analytics</a> |
                <a href="#">Database Design</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
     </ul>
</div>
```

Just add a containing block `div.wrapper` around the block that contains the links.

Adjust the CSS as follows:

```
ul#topnav li div.wrapper {
    padding-top: 40px; /* controls the gap between the menus */
    position: absolute;
    left: 0; 
    top: 33px; /* Add just enough height to clear the text links in top nav */
    display: none;
    text-align:Center;
    width: 100%;
    color: #fff;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
}
ul#topnav li:hover div.wrapper { 
    display: block; 
    background-color: yellow; /* to show the spacing created by the wrapper */
}
ul#topnav li div.sec-nav {
    background: #558ED5;
}
ul#topnav li div.sec-nav a {
    display: inline-block; 
}
ul#topnav li a:hover {text-decoration: underline;}
```

You can see the working demo at: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/cjTym

**How This Works**

Basically, adjust `top` for `div.wrapper` so that it overlaps the top navigation by a pixel or two.  That way, when you don't lose focus when you move the mouse off the top navigation block.

Add some top padding in `div.wrapper` to create the white (yellow) space between the two menus.

Finally, apply the background color to the `.sec-nav` block that wraps your links.

Everything else is the same so you should be all set.

**Aside**

I used `<div>` instead of `<span>` to wrap the links and so on.  Alternatively, you could use a span element if you change the display type to block.

Comment: but tell me how to make the second menu backcolor in full screen as the first menu

Comment: You mean the light blue should be the full width of the screen like the top nav?

Comment: yes that's what i mean :)

Comment: Try this http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/cjTym/3/